# How to find the Class with Reflection API

Tags: java, class, reflection

I am trying to find the type (Interface or class) of the "Class" instance. I can find isInterface() or isEnum(). But I want to check whether this is a class or not. WHY there is no method like `"isClass()"`? any help??

I have this code:

```
interface A {

}

class B {

}

public class ReflectionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        Class a = A.class;
        System.out.println(a.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(a.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(a.isInterface());
        System.out.println(a.isEnum());

        Class b = B.class;

        System.out.println(b.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(b.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(b.isInterface());
        System.out.println(b.isEnum());

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is a class"?  Are you using the term as defined in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.6)?  Do you want to know if something is not an abstract class, interface, or annotation?  All classes defined using the `enum` keyword are concrete classes, because `enum` is just syntactic sugar in Java and has not effect on the VM definition of a class which is what is exposed via reflection.

Comment: I Mean, the instance of Class (a,b in my example) is a template class or interface or template enum?

Comment: What's a "Template class?"  Java generics work via erasure, not by C++-style template macro expansion.  Generic type parameters in java do not have a reflectively available class object associated with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misread the question. Given that every type in Java is *either* a primitive, an interface, a class, or an array, you just need:

```
System.out.println(!b.isPrimitive() && !b.isInterface() && !b.isArray());
```

That treats enums as classes, by the way - you could exclude those in the same way, if you want.

Comment: Does `isInterface` return true for annotation types?  Answered my own question: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnnotation%28%29) says yes.

Comment: So no way to find as class directly with Reflection API?

Comment: @CHowdappaM: If you mean in terms of "in one method call", not that I'm aware of... but you can easily wrap the above code in a one-line method...